# how send result back in Spring 2.x

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a method which returns true or false based on some parameters. So I make an ajax call (using Ext.ajax.request). In spring 2.x version how do I send back the result? 
So for my controller I extend `BaseSimpleCommandController` and override the method

```
ModelAndView doExecute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
```

I want to know what would i need to do to send back just a boolean value. I am little confused as what needs to be done. I now i have to send back a ModelAndView type object but nor sure i should i embed a single boolean value in to this object.

EDIT: `the BaseSimpleCommandController` is specific to my project which in turn extends `AbstractCommandController` from spring. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There's a big difference between various 2.x versions.  Do you mean 2.0 or 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return `"true"` or `"false"` there is no need to use models, command controllers, etc. Simply inject [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and send the data directly:

```
public void handle(HttpServletResponse response) {
  boolean flag = //...
  response.getWriter().print(flag);
}
```

Comment: what about the request parameters, so based on the parameters in request i have to send a response true or false.

Comment: I haven't been working with Spring 2.x, but I guess you can either read them directly from the request (ugly) or try declaring command/form object in handler method (should work as well). Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Request params can be mapped via annotation in the method parameter, or through the request's parameter map

Method Parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void someCall(@RequestParam(value="param1") String paramName)
...
```

Where param1 would be the get parameter param1.  If you don't provide a value for the annotation, it tries to bind to the name of the parameter in the method name (paramName in this case).

Parameter Map

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void someCall(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
}
```

Hope this helps!